# PAR and Win32::Exe

Tags: windows, perl, par

I am running Strawberry Perl on Windows 7, 32-bit. I am also using Par::Packer to create standalone executables. The problem is that PAR::Packer uses a camel icon, and I want to replace it with a different icon. To do that I am using Win32::Exe.

After running Win32::Exe's update script I can change the icon, however now the executable no longer functions. After disabling the GUI flag, and enabling the console, I now get the following output:

```
Usage: foo.exe [ -Alib.par ] [ -Idir ] [ -Mmodule ] [ src.par ] [ program.pl ]
       foo.exe [ -B|-b ] [-Ooutfile] src.par
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--icon` option has been removed from PAR::Packer. Using Win32::Exe directly is the right solution. If the bundled exe_update script corrupts your exe, try issuing the actual Perl code on the command line - see [my answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23808560/1314944).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the --icon option to pp?

```
 pp --icon hello.ico -o out.exe hello
```

This came from the pp doc:

```
perldoc pp
```

[PerlMonks thread covers the proper way to create the icon](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=823968).

Comment: Appologies.  The info. I posted was from pp installed on Ubuntu. When I installed pp with cpan which came with Strawberry Perl and checked the options there was no --icon option.  I tried it anyway with a test icon I created with Gimp but, received  error "Unknown option: icon"  Being to newbish, not sure if I should remove this answer...