# Create exe with custom icon using Perl Par Packer

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a exe file from Perl script with custom icon .i have tried with these commands

```
pp -i "myicon.ico" -o file.exe file.pl
pp --icon "myicon.ico" -o file.exe file.pl
pp --icon "fullpath\myicon.ico" -o file.exe file.pl
```

but couldnt solve the issue.any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

**Update :**
for this code 
    `pp --gui --icon myicon.ico -o out.exe file.pl` .
    I have got an error as

```
Unknown option: icon
Binary 'myicon.ico' sure doesn't smell like perl source!
Can't locate method "maybe_command" via package "MM"
```

Comment: have you tried adding also `--gui` flag?

Comment: @FilippoLauria : Thanks ,for this code `pp --gui --icon myicon.ico -o out.exe file.pl` .
I have got an error as `Unknown option: icon`.

Answer (score 5):

The options `--icon` and `--info` have been removed from the latest versions of PAR::Packer. According to comments from the module's author on the CPAN bug tracker, the options sometimes corrupt files, and since they delegated to Win32::Exe anyway he now expects people to just use Win32::Exe directly.[1](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=95508)

Here's a handy one-liner to remove the default camel icon and add your own from a .ico file. As noted by Hariboo, your icon file must match the attributes of the original camel icon, i.e. 32x32 pixels.

```
perl -e "use Win32::Exe; $exe = Win32::Exe->new('myapp.exe'); $exe->set_single_group_icon('myicon.ico'); $exe->write;"
```

See the [perldoc for Win32::Exe](http://search.cpan.org/~mdootson/Win32-Exe-0.17/lib/Win32/Exe.pm) for other icon-related API calls. There is a script `exe_update.bat` that ships with Win32::Exe, but some users have reported corruption issues (e.g. in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21891564/1314944)).

If you're still getting corrupted EXEs, try downgrading your Archive::Zip, and then rebuilding PAR.

```
force install NEDKONZ/Archive-Zip-1.08.tar.gz
force install PAR
```

I have a separate, install of portable Strawberry just for packing and modifying EXEs with PAR::Packer. Be sure to pass `-X Portable.pm` to `pp` when using portable.[2](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1078554)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Daniels solution..

The icon file size must match the existing pp.ico file. This is 32x32.

When using anything larger or smaller I got signature errors.